# How to hide assets folder in windows release?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

when I build windows app, how to hide data folder? i do not want another poeple access this folder.

[image: this folder]

Answer (score 0):

- Click on that folder.
- Hit alt+enter on your keyboard.
- There will be an check box on general tab named hidden in the properties dialogue * box than opened when you did step 2.
- Check that box.
- Click apply. Then ok.

Comment: Thank you!
But when the client run project can access this folder.
what should I do to hide all of them from a client?